# Start Google Chrome process and call GetElementByID

Tags: c#, web

I did `Process.Start(CHROME)` to run Google Chrome browser.

However, I need to get the emelemt ID so I can do click.

Example:

I launch Google Chrome, it will navigate to some URL I tell it, and it will get the elementId of the button and will click it

I don't have any code to show, because I don't know how to do it.

Comment: I suspect that you are trying to write automation test case. Please confirm.

Comment: You need to use a webdsriver for this. Checkout Selenium too, it might help.

Comment: What I try to do is to make a bot, it will click the button every few minutes so I can leave it open.

Comment: Selenium + WebDriver will work for that too.

Comment: Thank you, I will check what is this thing called Selenium